# Returning runtime dependent Generic in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, runtime

I want to define a method that returns a generic class depending on class-internal configuration.

For example:

```swift
class MyClass {

    private var returnString: Bool

    func array<E>() -> Array<E> {
        if returnString {
            return ["Hello World"] as! [E]
        } else {
            return [1] as! [E]
        }
    }

    func changeThings() {
        returnsString = !returnsString
    }

    init(returnString: Bool) {
        self.returnString = returnString
    }

}

let myClass = MyClass(returnString: true)
let myStrings = myClass.array() // Generic parameter 'E' could not be inferred
```

How can I accomplish such a thing, only in a working version. I assume Generics are not the way to go, as my use-case needs runtime evaluation? Any way I could use type(of:) and such things?

My goal is to have a “clean” API with a type safe `array()` call where `[E]` can be inferred, like this:

```swift
let myStrings = myClass.array()
```

Comment: Do you expect the _compile time type_ of `myString` to be `String`?

Comment: Not sure why you need that, but as you set the `returnString` when you request the value (before the `myClass.array()`), maybe using 2 methods can solve your issue (`myClass.stringArray()` and `myClass.intArray()`) and call the one you need when you need?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, a string array (updated question)

Comment: @rraphael: `returnString` would actually only be set at initialization (updated question)

Comment: @LeoDabus Sorry, my mistake, I am indeed expecting a string array.

Comment: You move the problem, just move the solution: Use 2 different classes. One that produce an array of string, the other one that produce an array of Int

Comment: @LeoDabus I actually do not need the optional String (updated question). I would like to avoid setting an explicit resulting type as I already stated in the `init` that it should return `[String]`. At least I would like to put that resulting type to the `array()` declaration, so I can use `let myStrings = myClass.array()`.

Comment: @Pronful https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result

Comment: How can the compiler infer the type based on runtime information? Looking at that line of code `let myStrings = myClass.array()`, write it as `let myStrings: T = myClass.array()`. Looking at the program, what would *you* put in the place of `T`? Type inference is just a shortcut to type that for you. If you can't put a single, known-at-compile-time type there, the compiler can't either. What if something calls `changeThings()`?

Answer (score 1):

This is a misunderstanding of what generics are. This line of code doesn't do what you seem to expect:

```
func array<E>() -> Array<E>? {
```

This says, "for *any* type passed by the caller, this function will return an optional array of that type." No matter the type. Your function returns either an `[String]?` or `[Int]?`, which are only two possible types. Your function promised it could handle *anything*.

Types are promises, and you need to keep your promise here. You have a function that returns *either* an array of Strings or an array of Int. You can express "either" using an enum:

```
enum ReturnType {
    case string([String])
    case int([Int])
}
```

And then your function returns that:

```
func array() -> ReturnType {
    if returnString {
        return .string(["Hello World"])
    } else {
        return .int([1])
    }
}
```

And your calling code gets `.string(["Hello World"])`:

```
let myClass = MyClass(returnString: true)
let myStrings = myClass.array()
```

If `myStrings` were instead sometimes `[String]` and sometimes `[Int]`, what would the line of code `myStrings[0].count` do (there is no `.count` on Int)? Should it crash? The whole point of static types is to determine if something is safe at compile time rather than just crashing at runtime.

You could also adjust your promise. For example, you might say "this returns an array of things that can be converted to strings."

```
func array() -> [CustomStringConvertible] {
    if returnString {
        return ["Hello World"]
    } else {
        return [1]
    }
}
```

And then you could safely call `description` on the results. Or you could assign your own protocol that provided whatever functions you need.